# Problem with Image uploading to SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

I have problem with uploading image to SQL  database.
i have Methods Upload in controller Upload

dbData userDb = new dbData();

```
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileWrapper file)
{
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        Stream fileStream = file.InputStream;
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        int fileLength = file.ContentLength;
        byte[] fileData = new byte[fileLength];
        fileStream.Read(fileData, 0, fileLength);

        var image = new ImageTable();
        image.Image = fileData;
        image.Description = "Default profile picture";

        try
        {
            userDb.ImageTables.InsertOnSubmit(image);
            userDb.SubmitChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
    return View();
}
```

If i use this view page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

     <% using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {%>
        <input name="file" type="file" runat="server" id="file"/><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
<%} %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

everithing works great but if i want to use view runned on masterpage i wil get this error after i click upload submit button:

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

Know someone where is problem and how can i fix it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because default model binder can't create instances of classes that don't contain parameterless constructor (such as `HttpPostedFileWrapper`).

Simplest way around this is to just pull files from `Request.Files` (e.g. `Request.Files["file"]`).

Alternatively, you could create custom model binder for that.

UPDATE:

This is action method I used:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
{
    var file = Request.Files["file"];
    if(file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // ...
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: if i use Request.Files like..> public ActionResult Uploads(FormCollection { if (Request.Files["file"].ContentLength > 0)...bla bla bla 
i get error on "IF" line 
SystemNullReference exception >Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: It should work, you must be doing something else wrong. I pasted the code in your question into a view, setup a post action, selected a file, submitted, and it worked.

Comment: can you wrote me post action script u used ? 
I added this code: foreach (string postedFile in Request.Files){
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[postedFile];
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
and it works but when i am using code witout foreach cycle it isn't working